# java.netConnectException error when connecting to iSeries with IFSFileInputStream

Tags: java, ibm-midrange, connectexception

I have a simple Java program (using JTOpen) to connect to an iSeries and open a IFS file:

```
System.out.println("by ipaddress");
AS400 as400 = new AS400("130.3.3.333", "user", "password");
System.out.println("as400 connected? = " + as400.getCcsid());
//handle the exception if the file is null 
IFSFileInputStream as400File = new IFSFileInputStream(as400, "//PDF//00000104.PDF");
System.out.println("is available" + as400File.getPath());
as400File.close();
```

On one server in DMZ everything works fine but on a (supposedly identical) VM image on a server in a different building (still in DMZ) I get an error:

```
by ipaddress
as400 connected? = 37
IO security exception
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.PortMapper.getServerSocket(PortMapper.java:170)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400ImplRemote.getConnection(AS400ImplRemote.ja
va:975)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400ImplRemote.connect(AS400ImplRemote.java:390
)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400.connectService(AS400.java:870)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.IFSFileInputStream.connectAndOpen(IFSFileInputSt
ream.java:416)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.IFSFileInputStream.<init>(IFSFileInputStream.jav
a:150)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.IFSFileInputStream.<init>(IFSFileInputStream.jav
```

The connection works fine but then get a connect exception.

Any ideas welcome. Same ports are open in the firewall between both servers to the iSeries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple services each on their individual port and the initial connect only opens one. Check the [jt400 faq](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/i/software/toolbox/faqports.html) for the file service. I expect this port to be unopened in the firewall.

Comment: Thanks for response. I had looked at that information before posting and as we have port 8470 open, I assumed that would cover the file service use. I will get it double checked by our ops team.

Comment: Got the ops team to add that specific rule (8473) and this did resolve the issue. Seems it must have got missed when duplicating firewall ruls! Thanks for your reply.